# Content block not showing

Tags: module, magento-1, blocks

I'm trying to set up a custom block module and display it. For this question my namespace is V, module name W.
 I've created global config file, V_All.xml, in app/etc/modules/

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
    <modules>
     <V_W>
       <active>true</active>
       <codePool>local</codePool>
     </V_W>
    </modules>
   </config>
```

I've also created module config file, config.xml, in app/code/local/V/W/etc/

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
   <modules>
     <V_W>
       <version>1.0</version>
     </V_W>
   </modules>

   <global>
    <blocks>
      <w>
        <class>V_W_Block</class>
      </w>
    </blocks>
   </global>
  </config>
```

I've created class file for custom block, Yblock.php, at: app/code/local/V/W/Block/Yblock.php

```
 <?php
  class V_W_Block_Yblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
  {  // Methods
  }
  ?>
```

I've created a template file, Yblock.phtml, to output custom block data in app/design/frontend/Mypackage/Mytheme/template/Z/Yblock.phtml. In it I have:

```
  <?php echo "Test Custom Block"; ?>
```

I've tried to display block via local.xml:

```
 <?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <layoutversion="0.1.0">
     <default>
       <reference name="root">
         <reference name="content">
           <block type="w/yblock" name="yblock" template="z/yblock.phtml" before="-"/>
         </reference>
       </reference>
     </default>
   </layout>
```

However, nothing is displayed on browser. I've gone through my code and cannot find anything to alter. I wonder if anyone could point why "Test Custom Block" is not being displayed. I'll be grateful for all assistance.

Comment: z/yblock.phtml should be Z/Yblock.phtml as you file/folder  name start with uppercase

Answer (score 2):

The problem is resides in in you layout update xml file. You have your block defined like this.

```
<block type="w/yblock" name="yblock" template="z/yblock.phtml" before="-"/>
```

Here the template attribute is wrong. As per your template file name, it's value should be`Z/Yblock.phtml` instead of `z/yblock.phtml`. ie block attributes are case-sensitive.

The correct definition would be

```
<block type="w/yblock" name="yblock" template="Z/Yblock.phtml" before="-"/>
```

You can also resolve this problem by changing the file name to `z/yblock.phtml`.ie change the location of file like this : `app/design/frontend/Mypackage/Mytheme/template/z/yblock.phtml`

---

<sup>**Note :** Clear all cache after the changes made.</sup>

Comment: "As per your template file name, it's value should beZ/Yblock.phtml instead of z/yblock.phtml. ie block attributes are case-sensitive"  I've tried that but it does not solve problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: @raydona there may be multiple cause for this. you layout update xml file may not working. did you clear your cache after changes made?

Comment: Hi, I've cleared cache by deleting everything from the /var/cache directory. One thing I failed to mention is that in: System -> Configuration -> Advanced and in “Disable Modules Output” listing, I do not see my module listed. It seems the module is not being registered.

Comment: @raydona put your site in develper mode and look for any log errors. Most probably you can find out an answer there